# vim from terminal always defaults colorscheme and how to start gvim in fullscreen?

Tags: vim

I'm on windows 7. I've installed vim73 which also comes with gvim.

I downloaded a colorscheme and set it like this in my _vimrc file which lies in the root of my c:\program files\vim

```
:colorscheme wombat
```

When I run gvim the colorscheme works but when I execute vim from DOS then I just runs the default colorscheme. When in vim off of DOS if I type :colorscheme wombat nothing happens.

One last thing when I open gvim how can I make it open fullscreen.

Thanks

Answer (score 5, accepted):

To answer your second question and if you're on windows you can use:

```
autocmd GUIEnter * :simalt ~x
```

in your _vimrc to start gvim in fullscreen.

I can only guess why your colorscheme does not work inside your windows terminal, but maybe the terminal does not support the color range used by the scheme and it defaults to standard colors.
Maybe this [documentation](http://vim.wikia.com/wiki/Using_GUI_color_settings_in_a_terminal) can help you.

Comment: thanks the fullscreen setting worked great. i was thinking maybe you can't theme the terminal vim permanently.

Comment: Great suggestion, however, take into account that the use of 'x' is language dependent, I had to do some adaptation for my window setup.